# i got fatal error when updating wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

While updating WordPress version.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_is_recovery_mode()
```

in 
`/home/website1/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php:55 Stack trace: #0` `/home/website1/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(111): include() #1 {main} thrown` in `/home/website1/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 55`

Comment: `wp_is_recovery_mode` points to WordPress 5.2. Did you update to WP5.2 released earlier this week? This sounds like an incomplete update. I advice to update the wordpress core files manually. Make a full backup first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the update process has not completed yet. This function `wp_is_recovery_mode()` is in WordPress ver >= 5.2. It's not an important function.

Open this file `/home/website1/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php` in Notepad++, find this function `wp_is_recovery_mode()` and delete it. Then try to access the admin panel again.

Comment: After this you can re-install wordpress from `/wp-admin/update-core.php`, so you have the latest clean version of Wordpress